# Developing an OS designed for a USB stick : Some questions

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, usb, bootstrapping

My only experience in O/S development before this has been to create a 'Hello World' OS running from a Floppy drive.

What I need now is to develop a simple O/S to boot from a USB stick. And I have a few roadblocks:

1. How do I write to the boot "sector" of a USB stick? Are there any tools available?
2. Do you know of any good tutorials or guides directed towards USB bootloading?
3. I need to be able to read files on the USB; what is the standard file system on a USB stick? FAT? Does Linux natively use FAT to store/read files on a USB?

NB: I am doing this just for learning all the dirty low level tricks, that's why I don't want linux on a stick to do this job.

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894843/how-can-i-put-a-compiled-boot-sector-onto-a-usb-stick-or-disk 2) Off topic :-) 3) Make it more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There's no special boot sector, you just write the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) to the very first 512 bytes on the flash drive.
2. There are a lot of guides at [Pendriveinux.com](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/)
3. FAT works in most (if not all) cases. While Linux *can* work from FAT, you could just create another partition on the USB stick which will be ext2 (or any other *non-journaling* filesystem) and let Linux work on it. [IT Solutions Knowledge Base](http://www.itsolutionskb.com/2009/04/how-to-make-backtrack-4-persistent-installation-on-usb-disk-drive/) has an article about making a persistent BackTrack flash drive installation using an ext2 partition.

Answer (score 3):

[Boot from USB Stick](http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm)

Comment: mkbt from the link is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: agreed :) but atleast to test the real kernel easily.

Answer (score 1):

Just some answers off the top of my head (since I deal with low-level disk structure a lot):

1. You can just use a good hex editor that will let you write directly to a disk (such as [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)), or roll your own app that uses the CreateFile API (or the Linux equivalent).
2. You can check out something like [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/), which allows you to make a bootable XP image on a USB device.
3. USB drives are 99% FAT. Linux does indeed support FAT natively for reading USB mass storage.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an information. [Mac on Stick](http://portableapps.com/apps/operating_systems/mac-on-stick) will be a useful thing. You can get the core idea on file structure etc. Having a careful look will solve most of the above problems. :)