# Write a file to "Sector 0" using C#?

Tags: c#, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i put a compiled boot sector onto a USB stick or disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894843/how-can-i-put-a-compiled-boot-sector-onto-a-usb-stick-or-disk)

I'm busy creating a basic boot loader, it is for software that needs to run without an OS

I also want to write a small console app that moves the compiled bootloader to my SD card.

The problem I am running into is writing that specific boot loader to Sector0 on an SD card. The SD card is slotted into my SD Card slot on my laptop.

Can I accomplish this using a C# console app ? if not, what are my options on getting that boot loader on the SD card?

**Update:** The bootloader is written in C, I would like the console app that transfers the boot loader to be in C#

Comment: A bootloader in C#!? I would rather go for a low level assembly loader that can run another exe file

Comment: nope... bootloader is in c,  i would like the app that transfer the bootloader to be in C#

Comment: There is another [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894843/how-can-i-put-a-compiled-boot-sector-onto-a-usb-stick-or-disk) with an answer that use a specific utilty.

Comment: I would be *really surprised* if there were not existing tools for this: e.g. wouldn't cygwin + [dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd) work? (That is, don't reinvent the wheel just to copy it over :-)

Comment: While not an "exact" duplicate, as it doesn't mandate C#, I feel the duplicate question would sufficiently accomplish this task: if the question is about *how* to do this sort of operation in C# (e.g. use the appropriate WinAPI/elevations) then please open up a new more focused question...

Comment: @Steve, might not be in C# but it's the alternative i've been looking for. Thanx

Comment: why vote for close? I do not see any duplicate asking to write to boot sector using C#? If there is a duplicate, please post the link. @steve, your link is an alternative

Comment: Check out code from here http://dev64.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/physical-sector-read-windows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use low level IO API to write a file to a specific sector. Have a look at [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29) documentation for more info.

Comment: this seems to be the answer, reading through it i see that i can write to the boot sectors using the writefile method..

Answer (score 1):

A much easier idea would be to create an image file with your bootloader (and optionally, partition table and/or file systems) and use an external tool like [dd](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) or [Image Writer](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer/) to actually write the image to the SD card.