# how to write into USB boot sector?

Tags: nasm, boot, sector

I have written a boot sector program using nasm i want load that into my pen drive ( firt 512 byte sector) to make my pen drive bootable and run that simple program.my question is how to write that binary file into my first 512 byte portion of my pen drive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i put a compiled boot sector onto a USB stick or disk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894843/how-can-i-put-a-compiled-boot-sector-onto-a-usb-stick-or-disk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dd command](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/dd.htm) (see [this](http://bipedu.wordpress.com/2013/06/22/live-usb-linux-with-dd-command/) and [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/)). If you are using Windows, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894843/how-can-i-put-a-compiled-boot-sector-onto-a-usb-stick-or-disk).